# How can I set a MySQL user's password using a pre-hashed password?

Tags: passwords, mysql, hashing

How can I set a MySQL user's password using a pre-hashed password?

---

I have a MySQL 5.1.73 database server.

According to the MySQL documentation, in the newer versions of MySQL, creating a user using a prehashed password like this:

```
CREATE USER 'ans'@'localhost'
    IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'hash_string'
```

Is deprecated and will be removed in a future MySQL release.

However, I cannot figure out what (if anything) is the new way to accomplish this.

We use [Cobbler](https://cobbler.github.io) to set up our databases, and I would like to pre-populate my databases with the accounts they will need, along with the passwords they will use, without having the clear-text passwords in my scripts. I would have thought doping this would do the trick:

```
update mysql.user
    set password = '*E8D46CE25265E545D225A8A6F1BAF642FEBEE5CB'
    where user = 'ans';
```

But my testing, that doesn't actually change the MySQL login password.

```
mysql> create user 'ans'@'localhost' identified by 'foo';
mysql> select user,host,password from mysql.user;
+------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
| user | host      | password                                  |
+------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
| ans  | localhost | *F3A2A51A9B0F2BE2468926B4132313728C250DBF |
+------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
mysql> update mysql.user set password = password('bar') where user = 'ans';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
mysql> select user,host,password from mysql.user;
+------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
| user | host      | password                                  |
+------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
| ans  | localhost | *E8D46CE25265E545D225A8A6F1BAF642FEBEE5CB |
+------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
mysql> quit
$ mysql -uans -pbar
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ans'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
$ mysql -uans -pfoo
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
```

Answer (score 1):

When you hack the password into `mysql.user`, you are supposed to run

```
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

According to the [MySQL Documentation on FLUSH](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/flush.html)

> PRIVILEGES
>
> Reloads the privileges from the grant tables in the mysql database.
>
> The server caches information in memory as a result of GRANT, CREATE
>   USER, CREATE SERVER, and INSTALL PLUGIN statements. This memory is not
>   released by the corresponding REVOKE, DROP USER, DROP SERVER, and
>   UNINSTALL PLUGIN statements, so for a server that executes many
>   instances of the statements that cause caching, there will be an
>   increase in memory use. This cached memory can be freed with FLUSH
>   PRIVILEGES.

Now, you have to restart MySQL for the password to take affect.

Comment: 100%! The issue here is using `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` after inserting or changing the password.

Answer (score 0):

A bit old now, but for future reference, using the `SHOW CREATE USER 'ans'@'localhost'` command you can see that the new syntax is of the form:

```
CREATE USER 'ans'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH 'mysql_native_password' AS '*E8D46CE25265E545D225A8A6F1BAF642FEBEE5CB' REQUIRE NONE PASSWORD EXPIRE DEFAULT ACCOUNT UNLOCK PASSWORD HISTORY DEFAULT PASSWORD REUSE INTERVAL DEFAULT PASSWORD REQUIRE CURRENT DEFAULT
```